# Алгоритм Флойда,вывод матрицы расстояний

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Реализовал алгоритм Флойда, но задался вопросом,как сделать помимо вывода матрицы кратчайших путей,
ещё и вывод матрицы расстояний, который показывает через какие точки нужно пройти,чтобы получился кратчайший путь. (Пример как выглядит матрица расстояний на скрине)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int** mas = NULL;
int kol = 0;  

//вычисление минимального пути по Флойду
void minFL(int** m, int kl) 
{
    for (int k = 0; k < kl; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < kl; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < kl; j++) {
                if(m[i][j]>m[i][k]+m[k][j])
                {
                    m[i][j] = m[i][k] + m[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    cout << "Введите число вершин графа" << endl;
    cin >> kol;
    if (kol < 1) {

        return 0;
    }

    mas = new int* [kol];
    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++) mas[i] = new int[kol];

    cout << "Введите матрицу смежности графа:" << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < kol; j++) cin >> mas[i][j];

    minFL(mas, kol);

    cout << "Минимальные пути между вершинами:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < kol; j++) {
            cout << mas[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;

    }

    return 0;
```

[image: Матрица кратчайших путей и расстояний]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте массив для лучших соседей такого же размера.

В блоке оператора `if` рядом с обновлением `m[i][j]` добавьте

```
best[i][j] = best[i][k]
```

По окончанию работы основного алгоритма для данной пары вершин `a,b` пройдите от `best[a][b]`, пока не упрётесь в `b`.

**Пояснение:** `best[a][b]` хранит вершину, в которую нужно пойти из вершины `a`, чтобы достичь `b` оптимально. Если мы перешли в вершину `с`, то теперь `best[с][b]`  хранит вершину, в которую нужно пойти из вершины `с`, чтобы достичь `b` оптимально.

Начальная инициализация `best` - для каждой вершины `best[a][a] = a`, для ребра `a-b` `best[a][b] = b`, остальное заполнить спецзначением (например, -1)

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Pseudocode_%5B11%5D)

Comment: не особо понял, что нужно сделать по окончанию работы основного алгоритма

Comment: Алгоритм Флойда- Уоршелла даёт набор минимальных путей для **всех** пар вершин. Выбираете пару вершин, запускаете для неё восстановление оптимального маршрута. Надо для всех пар - для всех это делаете. Вот, кстати, [в английской вики есть псевдокод](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Pseudocode_%5B11%5D)